# I have two different classes in one column. How to test normality of each of them?

Tags: r, normal-distribution

A newbie in R. 
Considering this is my situation:(Actually my real situation is much more complex)

```
set.seed(100)
df = data.frame(SEX=sample(c("M","F"),100,replace=TRUE),BW = rnorm(100,80,2))
```

One column is SEX(male and female), another one is BW(body weight).
I want to test male's body weight normality and female's body weight normality. Then I can test equlity of variances respectively. At last, T test or other test for this situation.
But `shapiro.test` can't be used in this situation.  (like `shapiro.test(BW~SEX,data=df)`)

What should I do? I don't want to seperate the data frame or make new subsets.

Thanks in advance~!

Comment: `tapply(df$BW, df$SEX, FUN=shapiro.test)` ?

Comment: @thelatemail   Thanks a lot! it's also very useful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A "tidyverse" solution to this problem is described in detail here: [Running a model on separate groups](https://drsimonj.svbtle.com/running-a-model-on-separate-groups).

Briefly, using your data:

```
library(dplyr) # for mutate
library(tidyr) # for nest/unnest
library(purrr) # for map
library(broom) # for glance

df %>% 
  nest(data = c(BW)) %>% 
  mutate(model = map(data, ~ shapiro.test(.x$BW)), 
         g = map(model, glance)) %>% 
  unnest(g)
```

Result:

```
# A tibble: 2 x 6
  SEX             data model   statistic p.value method                     
  <fct> <list<df[,1]>> <list>      <dbl>   <dbl> <chr>                      
1 F           [50 x 1] <htest>     0.982   0.639 Shapiro-Wilk normality test
2 M           [50 x 1] <htest>     0.980   0.535 Shapiro-Wilk normality test
```

Comment: Thank you very much for providing more information !

Answer (score 1):

Oh I just figured out by myself...
using this code

```
with(df, shapiro.test(BW[SEX == "M"]))
with(df, shapiro.test(BW[SEX == "F"]))
```

I am glad I can learn more!

Comment: Yeah .. I am very appreciated that you provided me more ways to solve the problem.